# Vector space structure of the Zariski tangent space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a $k$-scheme and $p\in X(k)$. The Zariski tangent space $T_p X$ is usually defined as being the $k$-vector space $\hom_k(\mathfrak{m}_p/\mathfrak{m}_p^2,k)$. In general, this coincides as a set with
$$\widetilde{T_p X}:=\{f\in X(k[\varepsilon])\:|\: f((x))=p\},$$
where $k[\varepsilon]$ is the ring of dual numbers. I wonder how can we describe the $k$-vector space structure on $\widetilde{T_p X}$ inherited from $T_p X$ under this identification.

The action of $k$ seems to arise in this way: the morphism $k[\varepsilon]\to k[\varepsilon]$ given by $\varepsilon\mapsto a\varepsilon$, where $a\in k$, induces a morphism $\operatorname{Spec}(k[\varepsilon])\to \operatorname{Spec}(k[\varepsilon])$ and so $a$ acts on $\widetilde{T_p X}$ by precomposition. **Now, I'm not sure if this action coincides with the one inherited by $T_p X$ nor I know how to describe addition of tangent vectors.**

Also, if $X$ is a group scheme with identity $p$, then we can describe $\widetilde{T_p X}$ set-theoretically as the kernel of the natural morphism (of groups) $X(k[\varepsilon])\to X(k)$. Naturally, this kernel is a group. **I wonder if the group operation coincides with the vector sum.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functor-of-points perspective is very useful here in giving a clean answer to your question. When $X$ is a scheme and $R$ is a ring, write $X(R)=\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Sch}}(\mathrm{Spec}(R), X)$. We have a morphism of sets $X(k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2)\to X(k)$ induced by the morphism of rings $k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2\to k$ induced by mapping $\epsilon\mapsto 0$. The set-theoretic preimage over some $p\in X(k)$ is your $\widetilde{T_pX}$. We will equip this set with the structure of a $k$-vector space.

First we will define addition on $\widetilde{T_pX}$. In preparation, we want to define a map
$$
+\colon X(k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2)\times_{X(k)}X(k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2)\to X(k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2).
$$
Now,
$$
X(k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2)\times_{X(k)}X(k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2)
\simeq X(k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2\otimes_kk[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2)\simeq X(k[\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2]/(\epsilon_1^2,\epsilon_2^2)).
$$
Thus to define the map $+$, it's enough to define a map on rings. Take the map on rings given by $\epsilon_1\mapsto\epsilon$ and $\epsilon_2\mapsto\epsilon$. The map $+$ gives a morphism over $X(k)$ that is vector addition in the tangent space.

Scalar multiplication works similarly, along the lines you had thought: Given an element $a\in k$, we get a morphism of $k$-algebras $k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2\to k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2$ given by $\epsilon\mapsto a\epsilon$. Applying the functor $X(-)$ gives a morphism
$$
X(k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2)\to X(k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2)
$$
over $X(k)$ (that is, the triangular diagram I would like to be able to draw here commutes).

Edit:

I apologize as these sections I think are worse than the above. The main point is that if $A$ is a $k$-algebra and you fix a morphism $\phi\colon A\to k$ of $k$-algebras, then a morphism $A\to k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2$ of the form $a\mapsto\phi(a)+\psi(a)\epsilon$ is just the data of a $k$-derivation $\psi$ of $A$.

Below we'll dispense with what happens at least for linear algebraic groups over the field $k$. (Note that affine implies linear and this comparison makes sense only if $G$ is taken over $k$.)

**$\widetilde{T_pX}$ and $T_pX$**

This is essentially what the other answer discussed. On the level of sets, the isomorphism $\widetilde{T_pX}\to T_pX$ is given as follows. Let $f\in\widetilde{T_pX}$. Then $f$ is a morphism
$$
f\colon\mathrm{Spec}k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2\to X
$$
such that the only closed point $(0)$ of the source is sent to $p\in X$. We get a morphism of local rings
$$
f^{\#}\colon \mathcal{O}_{X,p}\to k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2
$$
that must send $\mathfrak{m}_p\to \epsilon k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2\simeq k$.
This is clearly the same as map $\mathfrak{m}_p/\mathfrak{m}_p^2\to k$. Moreovoer, a map $\mathfrak{m}_p/\mathfrak{m}_p^2\to k$ is the same as a $k$-derivation of $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$, and addition of linear functionals correspdonds to addition of derivations under this bijection. Explicitly, given a linear functional $\lambda$, one defines $d_\lambda(x)=0$ if $x$ is a unit, and $d_\lambda(x)=\lambda(x)$ if $x\in\mathfrak{m}_p$, and this is a $k$-derivation.

As for the map $+$, if we choose an affine open $\mathrm{Spec}A$ of $X$, containing $p$, we see that the sum of two elements of $\widetilde{T_pX}$
is a ring morphism
$$
A\to k[\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2]/(\epsilon_1^2,\epsilon_2^2)\to k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2.
$$
By definition of $+$, the derivation this ring morphism encodes (the function giving the coefficient of $\epsilon$) is the sum of the derivations we started with. This is the statement that the the isomorphis of sets above is an isomorphism of abelian groups. Scalar mutliplication is similar.

**The case of linear algebraic groups**

Let $G$ be a linear (equivalently, affine) algebraic $k$-group, and define
$$
\mathrm{Lie}_1(G):=\mathrm{ker}(G(k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2)\to G(k)).
$$
Thus $\mathrm{Lie}_1(G)$ is a group, although a priori it is not obviously an abelian group. As just the kernel of a group homomorphism, it is not a priori a vector space over $k$. We'll try to show that it's isomorphic as a group to your $T_pX$, and then that it has a natural $k$-action that makes this isomorphism one of $k$-vector spaces. Then we'll conclude from the section below. This material is totally standard and in Borel, Springer, Milne, various books of Conrad and co-authors etc, but nowhere did I find the precise statement that I need below (at least, not yet).

Recall that your $T_pX$ is isomorphic as a $k$-vector space to the space of $k$-derivations of $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$. Indeed, given a morphism $\varepsilon\colon A\to k$ of $k$-algebras, let $\mathfrak{m}=\ker\varepsilon$. Then $\mathrm{Der}_k(A)\to(\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2)^*$ sending $\delta\mapsto\delta|_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is a linear isomorphism.

Define
$$\mathrm{Lie}(G):=T_eG.$$

We will define an isomorphism $\mathrm{Lie}_1(G)\to\mathrm{Lie}(G)$ of groups. Indeed, a morphism of rings $A\to k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2$ is given by an morphism of $A$-algebras $A\to k$ and a $k$-derivation of $A$. For such a morphism to belong to $\mathrm{Lie}_1(G)$ means that the morphism of $k$-algebras is always the counit $\varepsilon\colon A\to k$ of the Hopf algebra $A$. Thus if $g_1$, $g_2$ are in the kernel, their product is $$
g_1g_2\colon A\to A\otimes_kA\to k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2
$$
and is also in the kernel. Thus the corresponding morphism $A\to k$ is again the counit, and the only question is what the derivation is. Of course, it just has to be the sum of the derivations for the $g_i$, but I'm dense enough to not extract this immediately from the slightly different treatments I listed above.

Comment: Dear Stefan, would you mind explaining why the vector space structure you have defined coincides with the one on $T_p X$? Moreover, do you know how to prove that this structure also coincides with the one inherited by the group structure on a group scheme?

Comment: Hi Gabriel. I've made an edit adding some discussion of this, although I'm afraid it's not very good.

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** "I wonder how can we describe the k-vector space structure on TpX˜ inherited from TpX under this identification?"

**Answer:** Since any point in a scheme is contained in an open affine subscheme and since the tangent space is defined "locally" we may assume $X$ is affine.

Let $I\in X(k)$ with $X:=Spec(A)$ and $A$ a $k$-algebra ($I:=\mathfrak{m}_p$ in your notation). Given any element $\mu\in Hom_k(I/I^2, R/I)$, there is a direct sum decomposition $R/I^2 \cong k \oplus I/I^2$ and a canonical map

$$ \phi(\mu): R/I^2 \rightarrow k[\epsilon]$$

defined by

$\phi(\mu)(a,b):=a+\mu(b)\epsilon$ where $a\in k$ and $b\in I/I^2$. You get a canonical map

$$\phi_{\mu}: R \rightarrow k[\epsilon]$$

defined by

$$\phi_{\mu}(x):=\phi(\mu)(\overline{x}),$$

where $\overline{x}\in R/I^2$.

It seems that if you choose $\mu , \eta \in Hom_k(I/I^2,R/I)$ you will get the map

$$\phi_{\mu +\eta}(a,b):=a+(\mu+\eta)(b)\epsilon.$$

and for any element $u\in k$

$$\phi_{u\mu}(a,b):=a+(u\mu)(b)\epsilon.$$

This construction seems to induce a $k$-module structure on $ker(X(k[\epsilon])\rightarrow X(k))$ compatible with the one on $(I/I^2)^*$. If $X$ is a group scheme you should be able to determine the kernel of $X(k[\epsilon]) \rightarrow X(k)$: There is a canonical map

$$u:X(k[\epsilon]) \rightarrow X(k)$$

induced by the canonical map

$$R \rightarrow k[\epsilon] \rightarrow k$$

and your point $I\in X(k)$. Hence if you assume $\phi\in X(k[\epsilon])$
with $\phi \in ker(u)$ it follows

$$\phi(a):=\overline{a}1 +\phi_1(a)\epsilon$$

where $\overline{a}\in R/I$ is the class of $a$. Given two maps $\phi, \psi\in ker(u)$ you may "add them" and "multiply with a constant $\alpha$":

$$\rho, \eta:R \rightarrow k[\epsilon]$$

defined by

$$\rho(a):= \overline{a}1+(\phi_1+\psi_1)(a)\epsilon$$

and

$$\eta(a):=\overline{a}1+(\alpha \psi_1(a))\epsilon.$$

This should type of reasoning should induce a $k$-module structure on $\widetilde{T_p(X)}:=ker(u)$ giving an isomorphism of $k$-modules

$$T_p(X) \cong \widetilde{T_p(X)}.$$

**Example: $Lie(SL(V))$** Let $V:= k\{e_1,e_2\}$ and $SL(V)$ be the group scheme of linear automorphisms of $V$ with determinant $1$, where $k$ is any commutative unital ring. Let

$$R:=k[x_{11}, x_{12},x_{21},x_{22}]/(det(x_{ij})-1).$$

It follows $SL(V):=Spec(R)$. We want to determine $T_e(SL(V))$ - the tangent space at the identity $e$.

By definition $T_e(SL(V)):=ker(SL(V)(k[\epsilon]) \rightarrow SL(V)(k)):=ker(u)$.

A map $\phi \in ker(u)$ is a map on the form

$$\phi: R \rightarrow k[\epsilon]$$

with $\phi(x_{11}):=1+a_{11}\epsilon, \phi(x_{12}):=a_{12}\epsilon, \phi(x_{21}):=a_{21}\epsilon, \phi(x_{22}):=1+a_{22}\epsilon$ with $a_{ij}\in k$.

The map $\phi$ induce a map $\phi^*:k[x_{ij}]\rightarrow k[\epsilon]$ with the property that $\phi^*(det(x_{ij})-1)=0$, and since the composed map $k[x_{ij}]\rightarrow k$ should correspond to the identity matrix, it follows the induced map $\phi$ must satisfy the above conditions.
Since the map $\phi$ is well defined it follows $\phi(det(x_{ij})-1)=0$ and this holds iff $a_{11}+a_{22}=0$.
Hence $ker(u)$ is the set of matrices $sl(V) :=\{A:=(a_{ij})\in Mat(2,k)$ with $tr(A)=0\}$.
Hence

$$Lie(SL(V))\cong sl(V).$$

The following post considers an intrinsic construction of the structure of a Lie algebra on $Lie(SL(V))$ and the universal envloping algebra $U(Lie(SL(V))$ (you must consider the algebra of first order differential operators and the algebra of distributions):

[Distributions of a group scheme as differential operators.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4088473/distributions-of-a-group-scheme-as-differential-operators/4094080#4094080)

If $G:=Spec(R)$ is a group scheme and $I\subseteq G$ is the ideal of the unit element it follows

$$Dist^n(G,e):= Hom_{R/I}(R/I^{n+1}, R/I)$$

has the property that if the base field $k$ is of characteristic zero it follows

$$Dist^n(G,e) \cong U^n(Lie(G))$$

is the $n$'th piece of the canonical filtration of the enveloping algebra $U(Lie(G))$. Hence $Dist^1(G,e)=U^1(Lie(G))\cong k\oplus Lie(G)$. Since $Dist^1(G,e) \cong Diff^1_k(R/I^2,k)$ is the module of first order differential operators from $R/I^2$ to $k$, there is a canonical structure of Lie algebra on $k\oplus Lie(G)$ inducing one on $Lie(G)$. This structure comes from the group-scheme structure on $G$.

Note: The construction is elementary - you must get used to working with coordinate rings and their maximal and prime ideals. In fact: If $R$ is a Hilbert-Jacobson ring it is enough to work with maximal ideals. Any commutative unital ring that is finitely generated over a field or a Dedekind domain is a Hilbert-Jacobson ring.

Comment: Dear @hm2020, bear with me as I try to understand in detail your answer. First of all, your notation seem to imply that you consider a point $p\in X$ and $R=\mathscr{O}_{X,p}$, $I=\mathfrak{m}_{p}$. So your morphism $\psi_\mu:R\to k[\varepsilon]$ induces a map $\operatorname{Spec} k[\varepsilon]\to \operatorname{Spec} R$ and an element of $X(k[\varepsilon])$ by composing with the natural map $\operatorname{Spec} \mathscr{O}_{X,p}\to X$. Is that what you mean? Why are you considering $X$ affine here?

Also, if $X$ is a group scheme, I do know the kernel of $X([\varepsilon])\to X(k)$ as a set

Comment: [...] it is nothing but $\widetilde{T_p X}$. This is clear from its definition. What I don't understand is its inherited group structure coincides with the vector space structure we're defining.

Comment: @Gabriel - I added a link that may be helpful.

Comment: Dear @hm2020, thank you for your answer. Even though I found it really hard to understand and I didn't understand the relation between some things you say and the question I asked, it was indeed helpful.

Comment: @Gabriel - in the link you find some details on how to construct the enveloping algebra $U(Lie(G))$ and $k\oplus Lie(G)$ in terms of the group scheme $G$ - maybe this is helpful.