# Hyperalgebra of a group scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

The following definitions are from Mumford's book on [Abelian Varieties](https://books.google.de/books/about/Abelian_Varieties.html?id=udFFAQAAIAAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y):

> A group scheme $G$ is a finite type scheme over an algebraically closed field $k$ with morphisms $m:G\times G\rightarrow G$, $e:\operatorname{Spec}(k):\rightarrow G$ and $i:G\rightarrow G$ such that for any finite type scheme $S$ over k, the maps $m$, $e$ and $i$ induce a group structure on $G(S)= Hom_{\operatorname{Spec}(k)}(S, G)$.

> For any closed $x\in G$ we define $$\textbf{H}_x= Hom_{cont}(\mathcal{O}_{x,G}, k)$$
> Now, the hyperalbegra $\textbf{H}$ of $G$ is defined as: $$\textbf{H}=\bigoplus_{\operatorname{closed}x\in G}\textbf{H}_x$$ where $Hom_{cont}$ is the are the maps $L:\mathcal{O}_{x,G}\rightarrow k$ which are continuous in the sense that $L(m_x^{n}) = (0)$ for some natural number $n$ (i.e. continuous in the respective m-adic topologies).

My question is the following. What sort of continuous maps are being considered? Are they morphisms between vector spaces or morphism between groups?

I believe the answer is vector spaces because the following is stated immediately after:

> $$\textbf{H} = \varinjlim_{Z\in \Sigma}\Gamma(\mathcal{O}_Z)^*$$ where $\Sigma$ is the collection of $0$-dimensional subschemes of $G$ and $W^*$ is the dual of any $k$-vector space $W$.

If my guess is incorrect, could someone please help me with the proof of the equality stated above?

Edit: I believe I see why my question might now be clear enough! My doubts would be answered if someone could help prove the equality mentioned above:
$$\textbf{H} = \varinjlim_{Z\in\Sigma}\Gamma(\mathcal{O}_Z)^*$$

Thank you!

Comment: You find a definition of the "algebra of distributions" in Jantzen, "Representations of algebraic groups". This is a related notion. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4088473/distributions-of-a-group-scheme-as-differential-operators/4094080#4094080

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An element of $\mathbf{H}_x$ is a continuous morphism of **$k$-vector spaces** from $\mathcal{O}_{G,x}$ to $k$.
To see that $\mathbf{H}=\bigoplus_{x\in G_{(0)}}\mathbf{H}_x$ is isomorphic to the direct limit stated in the question, we start from the obvious equality
$$
\mathbf{H}=\varinjlim_{S\subset G_{(0)}\text{ finite}}\varinjlim_{n\geq 1}\bigoplus_{x\in S}\operatorname{Hom}_{k\text{-vect}}(\mathcal{O}_{G,x}/\mathfrak{m}_{G,x}^n,k).
$$
Setting $Z_{S,n}=\operatorname{Spec} \prod_{x\in S}\mathcal{O}_{G,x}/\mathfrak{m}_{G,x}^n \subset X$, we can rewrite this as
$$
\mathbf{H}=\varinjlim_{S\subset G_{(0)}\text{ finite}}\varinjlim_{n\geq 1}\Gamma(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z)^\vee.
$$
Now it suffices to show that $\{Z_{S,n}\mid S\subset G_{(0)}\text{ finite, }n\geq 1\}$ is cofinal in the set of $0$-dimensional closed subschemes of $G$.
This is not difficult, so I leave it as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Any local ring $A$ with maximal ideal $I$ can be endowed with the $I$-adic topology, the topology where the zero element $0$ has as fundamental basis of neighborhoods the powers of the ideal $I$. This topology is also called "maximal ideal topology".

$\mathcal{O}_{x,G}$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $m_x$ and $k$ is also a local ring with maximal ideal $(0)$. Hence $\mathcal{O}_{x,G}$ and $k$ can both be endowed with their respective maximal ideal topologie, and $L:\mathcal{O}_{x,G}\rightarrow k$ said to be continuous if it is continuous for these topologies.

This amounts, as $L$ is a ring morphism, to be only continuous at the point zero $0$ of $k$, which amount to ask that the inverse image of the open set $(0)$ of $k$ is open as well in $\mathcal{O}_{x,G}$, hence contains a power $\mathcal{O}_{x,G}^n$ of $\mathcal{O}_{x,G}$, which implies that $L(m_x^{n}) = (0)$.

Comment: I understand the fact that $L$ is continuous in the m-adic topology. But, is $L$ is a ring/group/vector-space homomorphism? If it is one of the first two options (you say it is a ring homomorphism in your answer), my question is how is it equal to the direct limit stated in the question?